# QT - How to get values from a single row in QTableView

Tags: qt, sqlite, qtableview, qmodelindex

I have a `QTableView` with few records, a single row contains four columns.
I need to get these 4 index values (name, surname, age, username) in order to delete them in `SQLite`, so I need these four values to put in the deletion query. I expect to click on an every index of **THAT** row and get back all the 4 values.
How can I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see a problem. With `QModelIndex` you can get any data relative to given model index.

```
void GuiClass::onTableCellClicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    int row = index.row();
    QString name = index.sibling(row, 0).data().toString();
    QString surname = index.sibling(row, 1).data().toString();
    int age = index.sibling(row, 2).data().toInt();
    QString username = index.sibling(row, 3).data().toString();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Since Qt 5.11, siblingAtColumn is probably a better fit for this?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to handle clicks on your table view. For that purpose you can handle `QAbstractItemView::clicked(const QModelIndex &index)` signal and connect it to the appropriate slot. For example:

```
void GuiClass::onTableCellClicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QString cellText = index.data().toString();
    [..]
}
```

Comment: I tried, but if I click on a single cell the QString cellText returns me only that cell, I need all the cells in a single or in few strings better.